How to construct a triangle when its one vertex, incenter and orthocenter is given
I want to know how to find the other two vertices of a triangle when its one vertex, incenter and orthocenter is given.
I've tried many ways; thought about mansion theorem, the fact that $\overline{AH} = 2 \overline {OM}$, and also euler line.. etc
Neither of them did not really work out and I'm lost. I don't really know theorem that tells the relationship between incenter and orthocenter in the first place.
I would greatly appreciate any helpful ideas or solutions.
Edit: At least someone in the commments said that the problem is solvable.

What do you mean by 'interior' of the triangle?

What does "interior" mean?  Do you mean "incircle"?

yep it means incircle. sorry English isn't my first language :)

This is one of Wernick's List of constructions.  The "natural language" description is probably the one you want.

here is a useful guide to Wernick's problems.  Yours is Problem $#39$ on that list (I don't think the order is universally agreed).

@lulu Isn't that #99?

@Intelligentipauca  Oh, you are right.  For some reason I thought the OP wrote circumcenter.   And $#99$ is listed as proven to be solvable, though I find no explicit solution.

I voted to reopen as the question is interesting. But you should add a figure and give some other thought on the construction.

@Intelligentipauca it is a case of yet another perfectly good question being closed. I am tired of the serial closers on here. I voted to reopen too, btw.

The construction can be made, because one can find a quadratic equation for the inradius. But turning that into a reasonably simple construction might be difficult.

Extending @intelligenipauca's comment: For vertex $A$, incenter $I$, and orthocenter $H$, candidate inradii have the form $$r=\tfrac14(;\pm_1|AH|\pm_2\sqrt{4|HI|^2+4|AI|^2-3|AH|^2};)$$ where the $\pm_i$ are independent signs that make $r$ non-negative. The resulting circle about $I$ might be a (not-necessarily-unique) incircle of the derived triangle; or the $A$-excircle; or extraneous (if it surrounds $A$). Brute-force construction of $r$ is straightforward; a "natural" construction is yet to be determined. With the incircle available, construction of the triangle is also straightforward.

Wow thank you so much for there valuable information. I didn't even know that equation existed. Well, technically it's possible then. BTW, do you know where can I find that equation? Does it have a name?

@jackiechanfan: "do you know where can I find that equation? Does it have a name?" I derived it myself with a bit of Mathematica-assisted coordinate bashing and algebraic manipulation. (I'll sketch the derivation in an answer if I can find some time. (Oh, I guess I don't have to. intelligenti's answer handles that well enough by providing the quadratic equation having two of the values as roots; the other values come from switching $h\to-h$.)) Name-wise, "Blue's AHI inradius formula" has a nice ring to it. ;)

@Blue Oh I see. I really like "Blue's AHI inradius formula" lol. I searched literally every advanced geometry book I have and could not find the formula. I tried to derive myself with using AH = 2R cosA,
AI = 4R sin B/2 sin C/2,
HI = sqrt(2r^2 - 4R^2 cosA cosB cosC),
r = 4R sin A/2 sin B/2 sin C/2
. It kind of works but is astronomical complicated. So huge respect to your dedication on finding the formula yourself.

Here's a possible way to find the inradius. Let $A$ be the given vertex, $I$ the incenter and $H$ the orthocenter (see figure below). Set:
$$
AH=h,\quad AI=i,\quad IH=d, \quad \angle IAH=\beta, \quad 
\angle BAI=\angle CAI=\alpha.
$$
Produce $AH$ to meet side $BC$ at $S$. Then $AC=AS/\cos(\alpha-\beta)$
and $AS=i\cos\beta+r$, so that:
$$
AC={i\cos\beta+r\over\cos(\alpha-\beta)}.
$$
Note that $AC$ and $AH$ have the same projection on $AB$, hence
$AC\cos2\alpha=AH\cos(\alpha+\beta)$, that is:
$$
{(i\cos\beta+r)\cos2\alpha}=
h\cos(\alpha+\beta)\cos(\alpha-\beta).
$$
But $\cos2\alpha=1-2\sin^2\alpha$ and
$\cos(\alpha+\beta)\cos(\alpha-\beta)=
\cos^2\beta-\sin^2\alpha$, so the above equation can be rewritten as:
$$
{(i\cos\beta+r)(1-2\sin^2\alpha)}=
h(\cos^2\beta-\sin^2\alpha).
$$
We can then get rid of $\alpha$ substituting $\sin\alpha=r/i$:
$$
{(i\cos\beta+r)(i^2-2r^2)}=
h(i^2\cos^2\beta-r^2).
$$
Both sides of this equation are divisible by $(i\cos\beta+r)$.
After simplification we are left with
$$
i^2-2r^2=h(i\cos\beta-r),
$$
which is the desired equation for $r$. Instead of $\beta$
we can switch to $d$ through the relation
$2ih\cos\beta=i^2+h^2-d^2$. This gives the final form:
$$
4r^2-2hr+h^2-d^2-i^2=0.
$$
Note that the above derivation was made for the configuration illustrated in the figure. For some other configurations the relations could be slightly different, but in the end one gets the same equation with $h$ replaced by $-h$. Hence this case must also be taken into account, if one wants to recover all possible solutions.

However, the existence of a positive solution for $r$ doesn't guarantee the existence of the triangle: that happens only if $r<i$. In addition, the circle could be tangent to all sides but be an excircle.
The costruction of $r$ from the solutions of the equation is straightforward but artificial. I hope someone else will be able to give a simpler solution and/or a more natural construction.

Wow thank you sooo much for your dedication. About the r-derivation formula, I only tried using complicated trigonometric functions like AH = 2R cosA, AI = 4R sin B/2 sin C/2.. etc and that did not really work out. But your geometrical derivation is simple, straightforward and leads to the result without massive calculations. I shared this to my friend who were working on this problem with me and they were surprised too.
